# Erro ao rodar comando Updade-Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, code-first

Ao executar o comando `Update-Database` no Package Manager Console obtenho o seguinte erro:

> Value cannot be null. 
>   Parameter name: entitySet

Estou com apenas um model no projeto por enquanto

```
public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public  Guid ProjectId { get; set; }

    public String Title { get; set; }

    public String Content { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase Image { get; set; }

    public String Author { get; set; }

    public String FileWay { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DateProject { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DateUpdate { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateAudience { get; set; }
}
```

E minha classe `DBContext`:

```
public class DialogoContext : IdentityDbContext<UserClient,Group , Guid, UserLogin, UserGroup, UserIdentity>
{
    public DialogoContext()
        : base("DialogoContext")
    {
    }

    public static DialogoContext Create()
    {
        return new DialogoContext();
    }

    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

Não identifiquei o porque desse erro.

O que ocasiona este erro?
Como posso resolve-lo ?

Comment: Um monte de coisa pode ocasionar este erro. Poste os models.

Comment: @LINQ Por enquanto estou com apenas esse model que inseri na edição da pergunta!

Comment: Faz um teste aí, troca o nome da sua classe pra `ProjectTeste`

Comment: @LINQ mesmo erro! ;(

Comment: Ah, jovem. É porque você tem uma propriedade do tipo `HttpPostedFileBase`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso ocorre porque existe uma propriedade que não pode ser mapeada. No caso, é a propriedade `Image` que é do tipo `HttpPostedFileBase`.

Adicione o atributo `[NotMapped]` nesta propriedade

```
public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public  Guid ProjectId { get; set; }

    public String Title { get; set; }

    public String Content { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileBase Image { get; set; }

    public String Author { get; set; }

    public String FileWay { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DateProject { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DateUpdate { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateAudience { get; set; }
}
```